# Memory usage in EF 1 web service application keeps growing on each call - query cache issues?

Tags: web-services, entity-framework, query-cache, efpocoadapter

hoping some of you clever people can help me out here!

We have an ASP.NET web service app, using Entity Framework 1 and EFPocoAdapter. **The mem usage of the app pool running this web service keeps growing on every web service call.** We currently monitor its mem usage and once it starts to get over 1GB we recycle the app pool to free up the memory.

**We instantiate the object context in each web method in a 'using' statement so that doesn't leave open object contexts (observed with efprof).**

So I used Ants memory profiler 7 to track whats going on and after the first call to the web service (at this point the EF framework generates its view, etc), I've taken a snapshot. Then make the same call and take another snapshot. **Ants shows that the new objects created since the last snapshot are pretty much all related to System.Data.Common.QueryCache.QueryCacheManager.**

I know the point of the cache is to improve performance, but **in our case I think we need to NOT cache every query plan** as the likelihood of repeating those calls is minimal due to the nature of our main app / business.

So, my question..... **is there a way of turning off this caching**, or am I barking up the wrong tree here and there's something else going on I'm unaware of?

I've searched all over the web for an answer to this, and all I can find is the MergeOption property which seems to be related more to entity tracking for speed / performance improvements.

Comment: You can click on "edited..." and then rollback my formatting changes if you hate it. Unfortunately I don't have another input. Interesting question! Do you know if EF 4 shows the same behaviour? I guess `System.Data.Common.QueryCache` is some low level ADO.NET namespace used by EF but not specific to EF, right?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, it does help! Haven't actually tried using EF4 yet but I believe the query caching is a feature of EF in all versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't modify the data just select it, you can simply turn off object modification tracking:

```
datacontext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

It worked for me in a similar situation with Linq2SQL.